# mariaDB < DATA DIRECTORY > option can't create table in directory outside tmp-folder

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using:

- MariaDB 10.4.6
- Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
- Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64

I just started learning about databases. One major point was to have the actual data of the tables on a separate SSD.

Anyway, I found this example with which I'm supposed to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB DATA DIRECTORY='/path/to/folder/';
```

The problem is now, that I'm getting this error message:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `testdb`.`t2` (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")
```

I found mariaDB error 1005 but no further information about engine error 168. I assume that InnoDB is meant with "engine".

Further testing revealed that everything works fine if I use the /tmp/ folder and sub-folders of it.
The latter just if read and write permissions to said folder is granted to all users.

However, even with permission 777 on a folder I get the same error for every folder outside of /tmp/. This is independent of the mysql user and did neither work if root runs the command.

Changing the owner of the folder to mysql doesn't help either.

I thought that it may be apparmor. I've never had problems with that before because if I run:

```
$ service apparmor reload
```

I get:

> apparmor: unrecognized service

And if i run

```
$ systemctl stop apparmor
```

I get:

> Failed to stop apparmor.service: Unit apparmor.service not loaded.

So I'm pretty sure apparmor is NOT running on my system.

Hence, I'm stuck. I don't even know any longer how to phrase questions to ask to get any more information or closer to the solution of this problem :(

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a custom directory instead of the default path?

Comment: Author here: because I don't have enough space on the internal harddisk

Comment: So you get a new disk and mount it at the path?

Comment: That was the original idea. For testing though I just tried to do it with a path in my home directory.

Comment: Almost no one uses `DATA DIRECTORY=`.  Just let the files get created where they will.  Then move on in learning about SQL.

Comment: That is not helpful at all, especially considering that I already wrote that I don't have enough space on the internal harddisk.

Comment: I stumbled upon this post and following the suggestion https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217776/error-in-query-1030-got-error-168-from-storage-engine-when-creating-table by danblack resolved the error.. since I am using centos running "setenforce 0" had let me create the table in the data_directory given